# Why do I get this log - Resetting the last seen epoch

Tags: spring-kafka

I have a spring boot application that sends multiple topics to kafka.

In the service I use to send I have autowired this one.

```
  private final KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate;
```

WHen I use this kafkaTemplate to send to multiple topics I get the below info in my logs.

[Producer clientId=producer-1] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition ***** to 87 since the associated topicId changed from null to J09iQeooQtOuAyEfntux_g

To send. I create a GenericRecord

```
GenericRecord kafkaValue = new GenericData.Record(schema);
```

THen I set the values on the genericRecord
And when ready I send with this line.

```
kafkaStringTemplate.send(new ProducerRecord<>(sendMessageConfiguration.getTopicName(), textKey, kafkaValue));
```

Is the warning of importance? and if it is what am I doing wrong? It seems to me that all messages are sent.